# USB-C Docking Station to HDMI and USB-B (3.0)?

Tags: docking-stations, adapter

I currently have a docking station which has my keyboard, mouse, monitor, webcam, etc. connected to it. I connect it to my laptop with a single USB C cable.

I have an old laptop which does not have a USB C port. Is there such a thing as an adapter from USB-C to HDMI and USB-B? That way I can connect the USB-C cable to the adapter and connect that to the old laptop.

Comment: I like the idea, but older laptops generally have more ports and when you connect a dock to multiple ports it kinda ruins the idea of a dock